# wps_supplicant@.service not present in Jessie

Tags: wifi, raspbian-jessie

I've been following along with the [WiFi repeater setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-repeater-optional-with-bridge) and I've hit a snag. I am running Jessie rather than Stretch. I don't have `wps_supplicant@.service` in `/lib/systemd/system/`, just `wps_supplicant.service`. I've been searching across Google to find out if I need this file or not. I haven't found a conclusive enough answer. So, my question is if I need `wps_supplicant@.service` so I can use the configuration for `wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` or does `wps_supplicant.service` notice this file on top of `wps_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: You are using the wrong name. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are always talking about **wps_supplicant*** but there is no config file or service with this name. It is allways named **wpa_supplicant** (note *wpa* instead of *wps*). If you use the wrong name then you will not find it of course.

To follow the setup [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) you need the interface-specific version of *wpa_supplicant*, otherwise you cannot use `wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service`. To build such interface-specific versions a template is used, named `wpa_supplicant@.service.` On **Raspbian Stretch** it looks like this:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl cat wpa_supplicant@.service
# /lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service
[Unit]
Description=WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
Before=network.target
Wants=network.target

# NetworkManager users will probably want the dbus version instead.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dnl80211,wext -i%I

[Install]
Alias=multi-user.target.wants/wpa_supplicant@%i.service
```

As you can see it uses parameter `%i` and `%I` that are replaced by the item after `@` in the service name, e.g. with **wlan0**. This is different from the default `wpa_supplicant.service`.

**Raspbian Jessie** is the first version coming with **systemd**. It seems that early version does not support interface-specific versions of services, but I don't know. I haven't worked with *Jessie* since years. You should really consider to upgrade to *Stretch*.